# initializing dictionary prior to loop only returns last iteration

Tags: python, pandas

The following code only returns the last iteration into the dictionary. I presume I have not initialized dicitonary correctly?

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(18, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
mrkr = ['o', 'v', '^', '<', '>', '8', 's', 'p', '*', 'h', 'H', 'D', 'd', 'P',
    'X', '1', '2', '3', '4']
mylist = list(df)

idx_mx_vals = []
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if df[mylist[i]][0] > 0:
        idx_mx_vals.append(df[mylist[i]].idxmax())
    else:
        idx_mx_vals.append(df[mylist[i]].idxmin())

mx_vals = []
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if df[mylist[i]][0] > 0:
        mx_vals.append(df[mylist[i]].max())
    else:
        mx_vals.append(df[mylist[i]].min())

d=[]
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    d={df.columns[i]: [idx_mx_vals[i], mx_vals[i], mrkr[i]]}
print(d)
```

Resulting Output: Last iteration from the loop

```
{'D': [14, 971, '<']}
```

Desired Output:

```
All iterations (4) from the loop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting d with a new dictionary every time by doing `d = {...}`. You should do `d[df.columns[i]] = [idx_mx_vals[i], mx_vals[i], mrkr[i]]` (and of course you need to first define `d` as a dictionary, not a list).